# How to solve temperamental two list boxes stack each other in the user form?

Tags: excel, vba

I make two List Box in a user form.
In the design mode, the smaller List Box is behind the larger one.
There is no code at all in the user form module.

But when I launch the user form, the smaller list box is in front of the larger one, 
as seen in the animation below
[image]

and follow by another weird thing - when I go back to the VBA editor,
magically the smaller LB is in front of the larger LB which of course when I launch the user form, the result show the same (smaller LB is in front of the larger LB)
[image]

And the next thing when I come back again to the VBA editor, now the smaller LB magically is behind the larger LB, as seen in the image above.

Pulling my hair.
Maybe there is an explanation about this behavior from the experts here ?

I've tried bring forward, send backward, bring to front, send to back but still the same result. My Excel is Excel 2010.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What code has been assigned to "Button 1"? Does it only show the form? If you did not play with `TabIndex` property, they should behave according to it. Meaning that a bigger index will be on top of a smaller one... You can set them when the form is initialized, if still something strange. If nothing confidential, having an empty form, can you share the workbook in discussion? Maybe, we will better investigate to find an explanation...

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes, the code in Button 1 is just `Userform1.show`.  I didn't play with the TabIndex property. All the properties I leave it as default. What I did just create that two list boxes, the smaller one behind the bigger one. I'd be glad to share the sample workbook (which I just created the same way like before and it also still gave me the same weird result). How do I share it, FaneDuru ? Thank you for your comment. Oops... sorry I forgot, after seeing the result like that, I did play around with the send to back, etc.

Comment: Please, try using a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used. It will stay there only 7 days and after some time nobody will be able to see it, but anyhow without this action, I am afraid that nobody will be able to understand where the problem is...

Comment: @FaneDuru, very sorry when I open the link it gives me : Error 1020 Ray ID: 69567266fa8d49b4 • 2021-09-27 17:28:10 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

Comment: I do not know. It never happened to me. Try it again, please... If it still does not work, try sending to my mail account (in my profile)...

Comment: I've tried it a few more times, still the page gives me the same error, FaneDuru. I wonder if it's OK to share the file via google drive in stackoverflow ?

Comment: If I can download it, it will be OK. Only seeing it, will not be of any help.

Comment: Sent. Thank you very much for your concern and attention, FaneDuru.

Comment: Yes, indeed it behaves inconsistently... Theoretically, selecting a control, pressing 'Format' - 'Order' and 'Bring To Front' ('Send to Back' etc.) should set the Z-order, but it does not stay as set for all the next user form showing... I never played with such positioning and I did not imagine that it can be so inconsistent.

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes.... it seems the Format of the order has no effect at all. Anyway, thank you so much for sparing your time to inspect my case. For the time being, I use `.SetFocus' to whatever LB I want to be front in the initialization. At least it worked now :). Thank you once again, Guru.